# Spring Boot - Multiple Contexts "Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar' defined in class path resource"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created basic spring boot application for trying out multiple contexts, and here is the source code [here](https://github.com/programmer-git/sb-multi-context)

The structure of the application is :

- One main "root" context
- Two children contexts "api" ,"webapp"

The code runs fine, with just one child, the moment i add the "webapp" application context, it gives the below error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/admin/SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=MultiContextApplication
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
```

Where "MultiContextApplication" is the application jmx-name provided in the application.properties file as

```
spring.application.admin.jmx-name=org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=MultiContextApplication
```

Main.java is the main class with @SpringConfiguration annotation.

Can anyone please let me know what could be the issue,

Thanks & Regards,
Programmer

Answer (score 0):

[This github repository](https://github.com/bijukunjummen/sample-spring-boot-hierarchy) exactly what you want to implement. You should only config jmx for each context.

Comment: thanks for your response, the repo you mentioned also gives the same error when executed  :
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/admin/SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory..